# Neo4j return Node which relationships link to a certain Label

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to return nodes which do not relate to a specific label  at the end of the relationship links. E.g.

```
(EndTargetNode)<--MYREL---(SomeNode)<--MYREL---(SomeNode)<--MYREL---(SomeNode)
                                               /   |
                                              /  MYREL
(Node)<---SOME_REL---(SomeNode)<----MYREL----      |
                                                   v
                                               (SomeNode)
                                                   |
                                                 MYREL
                                                   |
                                                   v
                                               (SomeNode)
```

I'd like to match all `SomeNode`s which do not end with a MYREL relation to a Node with type `EndTargetNode` AND have at least 2 `MYREL` relationships. How would I go about this? Thanks

So far i've manage to just find nodes with the multiple `MYREL` relationships:

```
match (n)-[rel:MYREL]->(e) 
with n, count(e) as rels
where rels > 1
return n;
```

Answer (score 2):

This query will do it and reads just like your definition:

```
// I want all :SomeNode
MATCH (n:SomeNode)
// not related to an :EndTargetNode
WHERE NOT (n)-[:MYREL]->(:EndTargetNode)
// and with at least 2 MYREL relationships
AND size((n)-[:MYREL]->()) >= 2
RETURN n
```